# Cannot get envelopeId from envelopesApi.createEnvelope by using docusign-esign

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I'm working with DocuSign eSignature API and following this link 
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#post-go-live

everything was going great but when I tried to get envelopeId this function didn't return anything not even error

```
var envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi();
 envelopesApi.createEnvelope(loginAccounts[0].accountId, envDef, null, function(error, envelopeSummary, response) {
if (error) {
  console.log('Errors: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  return next(error);
}
if (envelopeSummary) {
  console.log("EnvelopeSummary:" + JSON.stringify(envelopeSummary));
  const envelopeId = envelopeSummary.envelopeId;
}
});
```

Comment: Are you doing anything on PROD or in Demo (Sandbox) environment?

Comment: Demo environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing data like this

```
var envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi();
envelopesApi.createEnvelope(loginAccounts[0].accountId, envDef, null, 
function(error, envelopeSummary, response)
```

but when I looked in node_module/docusign-esign I found this

```
this.createEnvelope = function(accountId, opts, callback) {
opts = opts || {};
var postBody = opts['envelopeDefinition'];
```

I used this code to pass data in parameters

```
 var envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi();
 var data = [];
 data['envelopeDefinition'] =  envDef;
 envelopesApi.createEnvelope(loginAccounts[0].accountId, data,  
 function(error, envelopeSummary, response)
```

It returned desired envelopeSummary

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the "`CreateEnvelope`" returned an exception, you could add a try/catch block to see if it's the case, it might be good for your code in general in case of future errors :

```
try
{
      EnvelopeSummary summary =
      envelopesApi.SendEnvelope(oginAccounts[0].accountId, envDef, null, function(error, envelopeSummary, response);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string error = ex.Message;
    Console.WriteLine(error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable API logging in your DS Demo account by following [API Logging Steps](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging). Once API logging is enabled then please capture and download the logs which will show the request/response (or any error) and will help you in debugging the issue.

Comment: that's the log i received:POST https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restapi/v2/accounts/4272753/envelopes

TraceToken: 51216ee0-5e8a-471d-b150-2761d7f9fea8
Timestamp: 2018-01-18T07:49:11.5477337Z

Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net

400 BadRequest
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 51216ee0-5e8a-471d-b150-2761d7f9fea8

{
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "Non-static method requires a target."
}

Comment: You should not put port number, the URL should be POST `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/4272753/envelopes`